# View and subscribe to Public Smart Mailing groups using {action.subscribeUrl}?

Tags: smartgroups, mailing, subscribe

I'd like to use {action.subscribeUrl} so email recipients can view and subscribe to public mailing lists. However, it does not show public Smart group mailing lists.

Is there a way to show Smart group public mailing lists using {action.subscribeUrl}?

Using CiviCRM 5.3.1 with WordPress.

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what the point of Public lists is if people can't sign up to them?

Comment: I'd like people to able to sign up for the Public mailing lists and the smart group public mailing lists.

Comment: The other non-mailing public lists are used, for example, for our public member directory. We don't want non-members to be able to add themselves to that group.

Comment: i don't think you should need to make a Group 'public' in order to make a listing of those contacts public, you should be able to do the latter via your profile settings

Comment: Group Visibility
Select 'User and User Admin Only' if joining this group is controlled by authorized CiviCRM users only. If you want to allow contacts to join and remove themselves from this group via the Registration and Account Profile forms, select 'Public Pages'.

Comment: Maybe your question should instead be along the lines "how do I show a public member directory without creating a public mailing list"

Comment: Thanks, I was able to change the group visibility and still retain the membership directory, so that worked! Back to my original question, smart groups still do not show up when I use {action.subscribeUrl}. I ended up not using any smart groups.

Comment: great. Since a Smart Group is a 'saved search' then in one way it makes sense that folk can't subscribe to it, but given that contacts can be 'added/removed' from Smart Groups I am not clear that offering a subscribe option should be 'impossible'

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, too. I'd originally wanted certain people to be part of the group (hence making it Smart) but wanted people to be able to add themselves, too.

Comment: Consider read this other question [CiviMail: What is the expected behaviour when unsubscribing from a mailing sent to a parent group?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16994)

Answer (score 0):

Your email could link back with checksum to a Profile that has 'Groups' field on it which should therefore show only the Public Mailing Lists (iirc)

Comment: I tried that, but the Groups field includes all of our public lists - not just the public mailing lists. We don't want people to be able to add themselves to the non-mailing lists.

Comment: Although we might be able to create a custom field, use that in the checksum, and include the custom field in the Smart mailing group...that might work!

Comment: Did you check it as anonymous - were you maybe see all groups because you are Admin?

Comment: I tried using it as anonymous but was still able to see all groups.