# Is there a way to limit the child groups displayed on an opt out message?

Tags: civimail, groups, opt-out

If you have a mailing group with child sub groups, when you offer an "opt out from this list" option, all child groups are displayed - including ones that the recipient  isn't a member of
eg
a parent mailing group made up of 2 child groups

```
             Main mailing group

  Child group 1 - parent = Main mailing group

  Child group 2-  parent = Main mailing group
```

If contact A is a member of child group 1 and she opts out of a mailing to Main mailing group she is shown both child group 1 and child group 2

Is there a way to limit which groups are shown?

Comment: feeling a sense of deja vu here - ah found it - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16994/civimail-what-is-the-expected-behaviour-when-unsubscribing-from-a-mailing-sent

Comment: ah  wish I'd seen that - I searched but clearly not very well.  Seems parent groups aren't the way to go;  pity they'd seemed easiest  way.  thanks for pointing it out